# Order of Constructors execution in derived class in Java

Tags: java, constructor

I have derived a class in java.
I noticed that the superclass constructor gets called before code in my derived class constructor is executed.
Is there a way to invert that order?

Example:

```
class Animal
{

  public Animal()
  {
    //do stuff
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal
{
  int var;
  public Cat(int v)
  {
    var = v;
    super();
  }
}
```

This is what I would like to do, but calling super() like that gives an error...

Comment: No it is not possible (At least in java)

Comment: This question can be answered by reading the Java language reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to invert that order. If you explicitly call a parent class constructor you are required to do it at the top of your constructor. Calling it later would allow a child class to access the parent class's data before it's been constructed.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't invert the order of constructor calls this way.  A call to `super()` must be the first statement in a constructor.  And if there is no such call, Java inserts an implicit call to `super()` as the first statement.

The [JLS, Section 8.8.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7), states:

> The first statement of a constructor body may be an explicit invocation of another constructor of the same class or of the direct superclass (§8.8.7.1).

```
ConstructorBody:
{ [ExplicitConstructorInvocation] [BlockStatements] }
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to call run the sub class constructor before superclass constructor. That's basically like trying to create the subclass even before the superclass gets created, which is impossible since the subclass relies on superclass attributes to get created.